# Two ways of slicing Python nested lists

Tags: python, list, slice

I have following code

`mylst` is a nested list:

```
mylst = [[507, 3, 30, 44, 522, 25],
[268, 40, 23, 54, 280, 67],
[424, 37, 28, 50, 438, 62],
[216, 47, 24, 50, 228, 72],
[562, 54, 23, 54, 574, 81],
[445, 63, 24, 59, 457, 93],
[217, 100, 23, 69, 229, 135],
[565, 115, 29, 65, 580, 148],
[596, 113, 22, 67, 607, 147]]

lst1 = mylst[4:6][:]

lst2 = mylst[:][4:6]
```

Strange thing, I get for lst1 and lst2 variables the same output:

```
print(lst1)
[[562, 54, 23, 54, 574, 81], [445, 63, 24, 59, 457, 93]]

print(lst2)
[[562, 54, 23, 54, 574, 81], [445, 63, 24, 59, 457, 93]]
```

How can be both the same?

Comment: In 1st method, you took a slice of `mylist` and made a shallow copy of the slice using `[:]`. In 2nd method you made a shallow copy of the whole list `mylist` and took the slice from that copy. And *it's not strange* that's how the language works.

Comment: What were you expecting instead?

Comment: It doesn't matter that they're nested lists. This works the same with flat lists and nested lists.

Comment: You can't "slice the second dimension" of a list of lists the way you were probably thinking. You'd need an actual multidimensional data structure for that, like a NumPy array, and it would look like `arr[:, 4:6]`, not `arr[:][4:6]`.

Answer (score 1):

When using [:], you are effectively selecting all the list, thereby making a copy of it. Here is what happens if you try to visualize it:

```
lst2 = mylist[:] # This is effectively creating a copy of mylist completely such that:
# mylist[:] = mylist
# then when tring to slice [4:6], you get the rows 4 and 5:
lst2[4:6] == mylist[4:6] # which is: 
                           [[562, 54, 23, 54, 574, 81], [445, 63, 24, 59, 457, 93]]
```

Now onto lst1:

```
lst1 = mylist[4:6] # Immediately gets the rows 4 and 5
                   # which is: [[562, 54, 23, 54, 574, 81], [445, 63, 24, 59, 457, 93]]
lst1 = mylist[4:6][:] # This is simply a copy of mylist[4:6]
```

Hence, they are both the same.

Hope this helps!